# BeautifulSoup script worked before and on another computer but stop working anymore?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am really scratching my head on this one. This python beautifulsoup script works fine in the same computer before and works fine currently on another computer. But when I try to run it in the supposed computer, the loop got stuck after going through a few times (the loop is supposed to go through 90,000+ times). I don't get any error message and the internet is working fine otherwise, I just don't know why? I have ruled out site changes (which has none) and my supposed computer is powerful enough to run it as it's perfectly fine running it before.

My python setting hasn't really changed (except I have installed virtualenv and flask, but I doubt it's related to that), I have another script using tweepy to collect tweets and this same supposed computer gets thousands of tweet-related info and runs fine without being stuck.

```
import urllib2
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def get_Search():

    for loop1 in range(0, 36): #36
        for loop2 in range(0, 36): #36
            for loop3 in range(0, 36): #36
                for loop4 in range(18, 20): # CHANGEABLE per script
                    for loop5 in range(19, 20): # CHANGEABLE per script

                        URLchar = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
                            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
                            "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"] # len(URLchar) = 36

                        url1 = "https://websiteABC.org"
                        url2 = "-"
                        urlComplete  = url1 + str(URLchar[loop1]) + str(URLchar[loop2]) + url2 + \
                            str(URLchar[loop3]) + str(URLchar[loop4]) + str(URLchar[loop5])

                        try:
                            page = urllib2.urlopen(urlComplete)

                            soup_FamSearchURL = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
                            page.close()

                            censusSubhead = soup_FamSearchURL.find("title").get_text(strip=True)
                            censusSubhead_decode = censusSubhead.encode("ascii", "ignore")
                            censusString = "Matched Heading"

                            if censusSubhead_decode != None:
                                time.sleep(1)
                                if censusString in censusSubhead_decode:
                                    print str(urlComplete) + " yes"
                                else:
                                    print str(urlComplete) + " no"

                        except IOError: # adding the error handling part so that internet breakage won't crash the program
                            time.sleep(60)
                            continue

                        loop5 += 1
                    loop4 += 1
                loop3 += 1
            loop2 += 1
        loop1 += 1

get_Search()
```

Comment: Do you have `lxml` module installed? Show the output of `pip freeze` command please.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be installed. pip freeze as "Django==1.7 Pillow==2.6.1 beautifulsoup4==4.3.2 lxml==3.4.0 matplotlib==1.4.0 nltk==3.0.0 numpy==1.8.2 pyparsing==2.0.3 python-dateutil==2.2 pytz==2014.7 siz==1.8.0 tweepy==2.3.0 virtualenv==1.10.1"